# Recibir correos electronicos de gmail

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, smtp

¿De qué forma puede recibir correos electrónicos de Gmail desde Python?

```
#Ya logra conectar con gmail.
import smtplib, getpass
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

print("email con Gmail")
usuario = input("Cuenta de gmail:")
contraseña = getpass.getpass("Contraseña:")

serverSMTP = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
serverSMTP.ehlo()
serverSMTP.starttls()
serverSMTP.ehlo()
serverSMTP.login(usuario, contraseña)
```

Comment: smtp es para enviar correos, no para recibirlos. Para esto último debes usar pop3 o imap.

Answer (score 0):

Como le comenta @abulafia, en lugar de `SMTP` que se utiliza para enviar correos electrónicos, debe usar `POP3` o `IMAP` (este último es preferible).

Ejemplo de uso:

```
import imaplib
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('sucorreo@gmail.com', 'suclave')
mail.list()
# Out: Lista de "carpetas" también conocidas como etiquetas en gmail.
mail.select("inbox") # conectarse a la bandeja de entrada.

result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")

ids = data[0] # los datos son una lista.
id_list = ids.split() # IDS es una cadena separada por espacios
latest_email_id = id_list[-1] # Obtén el ultimo

result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)") # buscar el cuerpo del correo electrónico (RFC822) para la identificación dada

raw_email = data[0][1] # Aquí está el cuerpo, que es el texto en bruto de todo el correo electrónico
# incluyendo encabezados y cargas útiles alternativas
```

Use la palabra clave `"ALL"` para obtener todos los resultados (documentados en [`RFC3501`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501)).

Este código no es mío, lo he tomado del siguiente enlace:

> - [PYTHON — IMAPLIB IMAP EXAMPLE WITH GMAIL](https://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/python-imaplib-imap-example-with-gmail/)
>   consulte la URL para obtener más información.

---

Adicional a esto puedo sugerirle el uso de dos bibliotecas (Traducir del Ingles):

> - [Imbox - Python IMAP for Humans](https://github.com/martinrusev/imbox)
> - [Wrapper for Python’s email and smtplib modules](http://tomekwojcik.github.io/envelopes/)